# Database re-evaluation of structure

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, evaluation

I have 3 tables, all with the same fields:

```
id  profile_id  group_id    comment     parent_id   registered  updated
```

Where group_id is the key to the table, as it represents 1 of 3 different parts of my website.

So group_id could be transformed into a type & special_id. For e.g. type = ('a','b','c') where special_id is the id of type.

Keep in mind that I have other tables in my database that relate to these/this 'core' table(s).

Would it be best to implement what I have proposed to improve efficiency/ size of the site or would it be best to keep the tables independent of each other?

Comment: depends on the table-size and queries

Comment: Basically, I have 3 tables that have the same functionality, would it be best to concatenate them into one, to decrease database size or would it be best to leave it as it is?

Comment: @Varon right ok, thats a useful comment! Can you expand? So if you can imagine, there were 10,000 entries in each table, it would be more effective to keep it as it is?

Comment: [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) seems a better fit for this question, as it's about database design. That's also where the DB experts hang out. They'll be able to weigh in on how things like the Principle of Orthogonal Design factor in to the design. You should be able to flag your question for a moderator to move it. Speaking of schema, the [best questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) include [sample code](http://sscce.org/), which, in this case, would be SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: If you don't have queries that use tables with different group_ids at once, it is definitely better to separate.

Because the DBMS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) should decide to load table in memory. That is fast and efficient. More data... let's say 1'000'000 rows is imho "to much" to load it in memory. The DBMS will only crawl the harddisk. So the better way is to separate.

But if you have only 10'000 rows each group_id and you have much queries that join these groups like `FROM a JOIN b ON b.profile_id = a.profile_id WHERE a.group_id = 'a' AND b.group_id = 'b'` it is often better to have only one table, because DBMS can optimize access times.

You can always check how DMBS handles a query with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.